# 'adb shell' are these two shells chained?

Tags: shell, escaping, adb, quotes, glob

Some aspects of `adb shell ...` behavior suggests these are two shells chained what stands behind that command. It means one shell of the host the `adb shell` sequence is invoked on, followed by target system shell. Command string seems to go through pipe of two shells.

```
adb -s $AdbID shell echo find  / -type f \( -name \*audio\* -or \
  -name \*alsa\* \) \( -path /usr/lib/\* -or -path /usr/bin/\* -or \
  -path /etc/\*  \)
```

results in:

```
find / -type f ( -name *audio* -or -name *alsa* ) \
    ( -path /usr/lib/busybox /usr/lib/dbus /usr/lib/faketime /usr.... long list of matching file system items follows )
```

List of items the patterns have been expanded against shows that expansion took place in target device file system, not on host where `adb shell` were invoked. That means glob expansion did not take place on host. It is due to escaping asterisks. It looks like host shell consumed asterisks escape characters and was satisfied. Unescaped asterisks went then to target device shell where they were consumed for globs expansion.
Myself tried out lot of other ways to escape asterisks in -path patterns. For all of them the same result as described above.

For Bash removal of quotes is made after expansions of all other kinds. No idea how does it work for shell on adb target.

But why command grouping - paranthesis - do not show that duality? Grouping escape was consumed, anyhow grouping is passed into goal command 'find', like it was one single shell. This observation belies thesis made above.

As one additional pro-argument for thesis made on input the naming A.. D.. Bridge (adb) seems to have very good reason - that piece of soft acts as a bridge between two -in this case- shells.

Is it really that way in case of adb shell one deals with chain of two shells?
Otherwise how to explain made observations? Is it possibly a bug of adb shell or target's shell?

Note: For the case here Busybox runs on target system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are two shells: the local shell and the remote shell.

`adb shell` uses `system(3)` semantics, just like `ssh` and `eval`. With this convention, all the arguments are joined with spaces and then evaluated by a shell.

The alternative is `execve(2)` semantics, used by `sudo` and `xargs`. With this convention, the first argument is considered the executable name, and the rest are passed verbatim as arguments. This is what you're trying to do, and is generally preferably because it's secure and robust, but `adb shell` doesn't support it.

To run `adb shell` with an arbitrary command, you have to escape values as appropriate for the remote shell, and then escape that whole command so that the local shell will pass it on correctly.

In this case you can simply wrap the escaped command in single quotes:

```
adb shell 'echo find  / -type f \( -name \*audio\* -or \
  -name \*alsa\* \) \( -path /usr/lib/\* -or -path /usr/bin/\* -or \
  -path /etc/\*  \)'
```

---

I can't explain what you say you're seeing with parentheses though. They should definitely be giving an error, and they do for me:

```
$ adb shell echo find / -type f \( -name ...
/system/bin/sh: syntax error: '(' unexpected
```

Comment: Thanks for input from you. Reg. grouping if these are 2 shells chained - for command discussed my expectation is: the 1st shell - the command pass through - consumes escape char ahead of group operator, 2nd shell in chain consumes cmd group operator; then the goal command `find ...` gets neither escape char nor group operator.